# how to set the time zone of INDIA in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am fresher in rails,

how to set the time zone of **INDIA** in rails 3 ?

where to specify this?

Please help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `config/application.rb`, add this

```
config.time_zone = 'Kolkata'
```

That should work.

Later you can confirm this by running the following in `rails console`

```
>> Time.zone

#output
(GMT+05:30) Kolkata
```

Answer (score 9):

You may just run 'rake time:zones:all' in your shell, you will find all the Timezones displayed for using in Rails development. From the above you can easily find INDIAN timezone as shown below.

```
* UTC +05:30 *
 Chennai
 Kolkata
 Mumbai
 New Delhi
```

Put any of the above names in your `config/application.rb` as follows:

```
config.time_zone = 'Chennai'
```

Just restart the server and you will find the timezone updated.

Thank you.